# iPhone 5 stuck at resetting screen

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I jailbroke my iPhone 5 a while ago and everything was going fine a couple weeks ago. I couldnt update or download apps from the appstore and couldn't delete or install tweaks from cydia. So i decided to remove my jailbreak. First i tried to restore with itunes, but my phone could't connect or froze (i tried on a pc and laptop). So i tried doing it from the phone itself, but now its stuck on the screen that you also see when you update your IOS (the apple logo with the white downloadbar below it). I already tried holding the power and home button, but when i turn it on again it goes to the same screen.

I'm hoping for a way to troubleshoot or fix this other than being patient while the charge on the battery depletes forcing a shut down/reboot cycle.

Comment: Why would letting your battery die fix the problem?

Comment: Hold Home & Power for up to a minute... eventually it should go into DFU Mode & let you restore from iTunes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed any tweaks that prevent restoring via iTunes such as **NO PLS RECOVERY**? If not, then try going into *DFU* mode: [How to get into DFU mode](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode) and iTunes should recognize your device. If it still doesn't, try removing all Apple applications from your computer & re-installing the latest available version of iTunes: [Download iTunes from here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).

Comment: @Jerrel Love u too! Glad I could help :)